# ngrx selector is called before the data is available

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, state-management

I have a parent component DashBoardComponent that calls loadLast3YearBalances action when a login happens

```
this.store
  .select(loggedInUserBankAccountId)
  .subscribe((loggedBankAccountId) => {
    this.store.dispatch(DashBoardActions.loadLast3YearBalances( { loggedBankAccountId }));
  });
```

this actions call an effect

```
  loadlast3YearsBlances$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(DashBoardActions.loadLast3YearBalances),
  concatMap((action) =>
    this.graphHttpService.getYearlyBalance(action.loggedBankAccountId).pipe(
      tap((data) => {
        this.notifyService.showSuccess(
          'Last Three Year Balances Loaded',
          'Sucess'
        );
      }),
      map((balances) =>
        DashBoardActions.last3YearBalancesLoaded({ balances })
      ),
       catchError((err) => {
        this.notifyService.showError(
          'Error While Loading Last Three Year Balances',
          'Error'
        );
        return of(DashBoardActions.last3YearBalancesLoadError());
      })
    )
  )
)
```

);

DashBoardActions.last3YearBalancesLoaded  this action  tells the system that loadLast3YearBalances has completed.

but this Parent component has a child graph (child component) placed in its html.

```
   <app-total-balance-graph></app-total-balance-graph>
```

this total balance graph use a sector.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.last3YearBalances$ = this.store.pipe(
  select(last3YearBalancesSelector)
); 
 ....
```

this selector is defined like this

```
        import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

    export const last3YearBalancesSelector = createSelector(
    state => state['dash'],
    (dash) => dash['lastThreeYearBalances']
    );
```

the reducers are define like this

```
        import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
    import { LineGraphData } from '../../total-balance-graph/lineGraphData';
    import { DashBoardActions } from '../action-types';


    export interface DashState {
    lastThreeYearBalances: LineGraphData[];
    }

    export const initialDashState: DashState = {
        lastThreeYearBalances: null
    };

    /* export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<DashState> = {

    }; */

    export const dashReducer = createReducer(
        initialDashState,
        on(DashBoardActions.last3YearBalancesLoaded, (state, action) => {
            return {
                lastThreeYearBalances: action.balances
            };
        })
    );
```

the reducer sets 'lastThreeYearBalances' property on action last3YearBalancesLoaded but before this happens 'last3YearBalancesSelector' is called. and at that time 'lastThreeYearBalances' property is not set. and i get error.

what is that i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector returns an Observable, which may not have emitted anything yet (technically it will have emitted the initial state). If, in your component, you need to be sure you're only using emissions containing data, you can filter for that in your component. A simple example that checks that the emission is truthy is to add:

```js
filter(data => !!data)
```

to the Observable `pipe` in the consumer component. This way, only truthy values will pass through. Mix this with:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="myObservable$ | async as data">
</ng-container>
```

around the area of the template which consumes the Observable, and you'll ensure that you don't get any errors.